# PDFormXObject Processing

Tags: java, pdf, groovy, pdfbox

I have a PostScript Sample that illustrates creating a Form. If I convert the PostScript to PDF, I can enumerate the FormXObject quite easily but how do I get access to the content? For example

```
/SForm <<     
    /FormType 1              % all forms are FormType 1
    /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0]   % no scaling or translating
    /BBox [ 0 -10 100 100 ]  % hack - should really calculate the width of the string 
                             % and the height of the font allowing for descenders etc
    /PaintProc {
        pop
        0 0 moveto           % assume that the translate has set the current point
        (XObject String) show
        0 24 moveto
        (Line Two) show        
    } bind   
>> def
```

Translates to

```
7 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Form/FormType 1/BBox[0 -10 100 100]/Resources 6 0 R/Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]/Length 98>>
stream
/GS1 gs
BT
/F1 1 Tf
11 0 0 11 0 0 Tm
0 g
0 Tc
0 Tw
(XObject String)Tj
0 2.1818 TD
(Line Two)Tj
ET

endstream
endobj
```

How can I obtain the information between `stream` and `endstream`. I had assumed that this would have been a relatively simple operation but I've not managed to retrieve the content. If I use something like the following (in my Groovy Code) then I get the information between << >> (the dictionary) but not the actual PDF operators that do that actual marking (from the PostScript PaintProc).

```
 Iterable<COSName> names = pdDoc.getPage(pageNum).getResources().getXObjectNames();
 for (COSName name:names){
    def xObject = pdResources.getXObject(name)
    if (xObject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
       println xObject.getContentStream().dump()
    }
 }
```

Actually, it would suit my purpose to get the content between the `BT` and `ET` operators. The main focus is to find the "definition" of the FormXObject along with its content and not really to explore where the FormXObject is used in the page content.

Obviously I have overlooked something but what?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a PostScript question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xObject.getContents()` returns you an `InputStream` from which you can read the stream contents.

Comment: And that one can be fed to `PDFStreamParser` to get tokens. The `RemoveAllText.java` example from the source code download does this. For some more insights, run PDFDebugger on the PDF.

Comment: Thank you both, that was a big help.